# My application URL page is not opening instead Tomcat page is opening by default

Tags: java, xml, jsp, tomcat

I tried to open the my application url but it re-directs to Tomcat page as 
follows,
[image]

But when I enter the next page by editing in URL it is re-directing to the application.

I checked the web.xml and jsp page everything looks fine for me.

Please help me to find the root cause of the issue.

Comment: How did you deploy your application? For example, if you put a .war into webapps it must be called ROOT.war to run in the root context.

Comment: We have the separate server and in web app i do have ROOT folder but not in the war format . I am seeing only the Root folder

Comment: remove the webapps/ROOT directory and put your ROOT.war into webapps.

Answer (score 0):

Way of doing this is as follows.

1. Create ROOT/index.html(or index.jsp) in your webapps and then
   redirect to your page(Make sure to create WEB-INF folder also inside ROOT directory). Tomcat first check this directory if no app name specified after url:port.
2. According to the Apache Tomcat docs, you can change the application by creating a ROOT.xml file. See this for more info:

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html

"The default web application may be defined by using a file called ROOT.xml."

Comment: @ Kanchan Kumar Thanks for suggestion, I followed the above steps but now I am getting the error message as 
 " This page isn’t working
myapp.personapp.com redirected you too many times.
Try clearing your cookies."                                                                   If I tried to enter the next page manually in the URL as https://myapp.personapp.com/personpage1/person  then the login page is opening.